What is an English transliteration for for Korean word for "squash" or "zuchinni"?
"squash" and "zucchini" are English words.

Please consider the following Korean words...
호박
호박
애호박

When we use English writing to record Korean sounds, do we write "H-AW-N-AW?"
What transliteration do you recommend?

are these two different questions? Are you asking about transliteration or translation? What is "H-AW-N-AW?"?

Why is "호박" listed twice? ¶ And "zucchini" is an Italian word. (English borrowed it, and still pronounces the "ch" the way it would be in Italian, not in English.)

The question is deeply confusing, but I'll try my best:
호박 is transliterated (romanized) to hobak, and translated to pumpkin/squash
애호박 is transliterated to ayhobak, and translated to zucchini
I have no idea what you mean by 'H-AW-N-AW', please clarify.

애호박 is aehobak in the current romanization (and also MR romanization). "ay" as a representation of "ㅐ" is (as far as I know) only officially used in Yale romanization, which is pretty much only used by linguists.
